# Controlled access to list of entities vs get/set access in domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity

When designing a domain, either way of following approaches can be used to access list of child entities inside a parent entity.

**1. Get/Set**

Following approach is straight forward and simple to implement, but anyone can overwrite the Orders collection.

```csharp
public User 
{
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

or

**2. Controlled Access**

Following is bit complicated, however it provides it's orders list controlled access.

```csharp
public User 
{
    private IList<Order> _orders;

    public User()
    {
        _orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public IList<Order> Orders
    {
        get
        {
            return new new ReadOnlyCollection<Order>(_orders);
        }
    }

    public void Add(Order order)
    {  
        order.User = this;
        _orders.Add(order);
    }

    public void Remove(Order order)
    {
        if (_orders.Contains(order)
        { 
            order.User = null;
            _orders.Remove(order);
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach clearly has it's benefits, but it also increase the number of lines in the code (imagine when few of the collections are in the entity). So the question is, is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Maybe [this might be a interesting reading](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important question: in the first example, where does the code that enforces the business invariant live?

The first approach looks simple and straight forward because all the hard stuff has been moved somewhere else!

So, in order:

```
public User 
{
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

This is bad, because the constraint on the list of users has been moved outside the entity.

```
user.getOrders().add(invariantViolatingOrder);
```

Your second approach is better, but still has problems

```
public User 
{
    public IList<Order> Orders
    {
        get
        {
            return new new ReadOnlyCollection<Order>(_orders);
        }
    }
}
```

This protects the collection against change, but it doesn't protect the Order's from being changed in a way that violates the invariant.

```
user.getOrders().getOrder(2).invariantViolatingChange();
```

The order entity can enforce an invariant of its own state, but it can't enforce an invariant of the combined state.  (Contrived example: this particular user is only allowed $20 dollars of orders.  You have to check the entire collection to verify that it's ok to change this one order).

The easiest way to ensure that an invariant is enforced at every point that changes the state of an entity, is to make sure there is only one place where the state can be changed, and enforce it there.  In OO terms, this is "encapsulation".

```
public User 
{
    public IList<Order> Orders
    {
        get
        {
            // By returning a copy of the state, we ensure that nothing
            // outside the user can change its state.
            IList<Order> readOnly = new List<Order>();

            for (Order o : _orders) {
                // Turtles all the way down: this depends on the order
                // providing copies of its own state.
                readOnly.add(o.clone());
            }

            return readOnly ;
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to treat the internal state of an entity as an immutable value type.  Getting *immutable* state is perfectly fine, because there's no way that the immutable state can be used to violate the business invariant.

But again, this second solution is turtles all the way down; you have to be careful about including entities in a value object.

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason why the IEnumerable interface is used. This allows your public getter property to return a collection you can iterate over but cannot add or remove items from. The underlying read/write collection could be an IList.

```csharp
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    private IList<Order> orders;

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return orders; }
    }

    public Order AddOrder(Product p)
    {
        Order o = new Order(this, p);

        orders.Add(o);

        return o;
    }
}
```

Now you can tightly control how orders get added by forcing clients of your code to use the "AddOrder" method. Furthermore, you can't accidentally add an order for another User to this User. You can even go so far as to mark the Order constructor internal so code outside this assembly is unable to create orders without a User:

```csharp
public class Order
{
    internal Order(User user, Product product)
    {
        User = user;
        Product = product;
    }

    public Product Product { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
}
```

And a sample usage:

```csharp
User user = usersRepository.Find(123);
Product product = productsRepository.Find(321);

// Compiler won't allow this because the Order constructor is marked "internal"
Order order = new Order(user, product);

// This is allowed because the User class is in the same Assembly as the Order class
Order order = user.AddOrder(product);
```

This approach also guards against trying to add an order to a user where the Order object references a different user:

```csharp
User user1 = usersRepository.Find(123);
User user2 = usersRepository.Find(1003);
Product product = productsRepository.Find(30);

// Create the "order" object for "user2"
Order order = new Order(user2, product);

// Add the "order" object to "user1" -- oops!
user1.Orders.Add(order);
```

The code above compiles fine, but results in a runtime error that could quite possibly be difficult to track down.

I realize this expanded beyond your original question, but I think looking at the larger system and the other use cases is essential for providing an answer.

In my opinion, you don't need a "read only collection" or a clone of the existing collection. If your Order class implements encapsulation properly, no one can change the data for an Order without the business rules being enforced by the Order object itself, so there is no need to clone objects in memory.

1. Create a private field as an IList or ICollection
2. Create a public getter property returning the read/write collection as an IEnumerable object
3. Each object in the collection must implement encapsulation properly so even if some other object changes the data, the data is still changed according to the business rules

Comment: Someone could cast the Orders to IList, and try to manipulate isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But now you are asking for trouble, and if you get into trouble it is your own fault. :)